# Lazy loading doesn't generate any chunks Angular 8

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

So i have followed the guide on lazy loading modules, but there is no lazy loading if i open the network tab from `DevTools`.

Here's my implemenation:

My `AppRoutingModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'route1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./featureModules/feature1/feature1.module').then(
        mod => mod.Feature1Module
      ),
    canLoad: [Feature1Guard]
  },
 {
    path: 'route2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./featureModules/feature2/feature2.module').then(
        mod => mod.Feature2Module
      ),
    canLoad: [Feature2Guard]
  },
   {
    path: 'route3',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./featureModules/feature3/feature3.module').then(
        mod => mod.Feature3Module
      ),
    canLoad: [Feature3Guard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and each `FeatureModule` looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Feature1Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Feature1Component],
  imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [Feature1Service],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Feature1Module{}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: in your ngsw-config.json do you have -  "installMode": "lazy"?

Comment: If you do 'ng build' (without --prod), then look in your dist folder, do you see different .js files with the names of your modules?

Comment: No difference. InstallMode is set to lazy.

Comment: Do i have to enable ivy?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with Ivy.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code examples.

Comment: Can the import order be a problem? I tried different 'combinations' ... Now i'm importing the RouterModule before the FeatureModules.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by removing the `exports:[RouterModule]` from `feature modules`. I don't know if that was the issue but now it built the chunks.